# Регулярные выражения - точное совпадение по поиску

Tags: php

уважаемые программисты)
!!! как правильно составить рег. выражение, чтобы находило по точному поиску

Например:
$name = (А тут слониха)
$bd_category_one->params1 = (слон|сло)
должно вывести '0' а не 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
echo 'поиск слова - '.$bd_category_one->params1;
echo "<hr>";
echo 'категория - '.$bd_category_one->name;
echo "<hr>";
echo 'название товара - '.$name;

dd(preg_match("/\b$bd_category_one->params1\b/i",$name));
```

Comment: 1. preq_quote 2. модификатор u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо @Ипатьев

```
dd(preg_match("/\b($bd_category_one->params1)\b/u",$name));
```